# HTTP ERROR 500 when editing entry with image in EE2

Tags: file-manager, error-500

Updated from EE 2.7.3 to 2.11.3. Entries with a fieldtype of file for images that have a image in place can now not be opened to edit them. They give a HTTP ERROR 500.

Entries without an image in that field are fine to open for edit.

The file manager still shows all 3 directories that are configured. They also show the images. But when I try to sync a folder or want to download an image I get HTTP ERROR 500 as well.

I can't find any place for further help of that problem for the moment. So I try here.

Comment: Check your server logs. They may give some indication as to what is happening. Also, r u confident that the paths are 100% (try uploading a new img).

Comment: Thank you stuartmcd69, that lead to further investigation. See my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: The PHP options on our server 'Display errors' and 'log_errors' were 'Off'. Switched them to 'On'.

Then I set $debug = 1; in index.php in folder expressionengine.

Now I could see

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\finfo_open() in /home/foo/bar/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php on line 117
```

Second: on the server with PHP 5.5 the 'fileinfo' was disabled. Enabled it. Bingo! Problem solved.